# In Ionic 3, how do I call a method that is inside a tab class?

Tags: typescript, ionic3

I am coding an Ionic app which has a "home" page, with 3 tabs. I am trying to make a search bar available for those tabs, by calling a method inside the selected tab's class when the search term is changed. This is the home page:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>{{title}}</ion-title>
        <ion-buttons end>
            <button [hidden]="title != 'Meu Cadastro'" ion-button color="dark" (click)="logout()">
                <ion-icon name="log-out"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-navbar>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" (ionInput)="setFilteredItems()"></ion-searchbar>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content >
    <ion-tabs #homeTabs>
        <ion-tab [root]="tabAten" tabTitle="Atendimentos" [rootParams]="innerInstance" tabIcon="construct"></ion-tab>
        <ion-tab [root]="tabEquip" tabTitle="Equipamentos" [rootParams]="innerInstance" tabIcon="build"></ion-tab>
        <ion-tab [root]="tabCad" tabTitle="Meu Cadastro" [rootParams]="innerInstance" tabIcon="contact"></ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>

</ion-content>

import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, AlertController, Tabs } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NativePageTransitions, NativeTransitionOptions } from "@ionic-native/native-page-transitions";

import { AtendimentosPage } from "../home/atendimentos/atendimentos";
import { EquipamentosPage } from "../home/equipamentos/equipamentos";
import { MeuCadastroPage } from "../home/meu_cadastro/meu_cadastro";

var instance: any;

@Component({
selector: 'page-home',
templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {

title: String;

@ViewChild('homeTabs') tabs: Tabs;

tabAten: any;
tabEquip: any;
tabCad: any;

searchTerm: string = '';

innerInstance: any;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController
    , private alertCtrl: AlertController
    , private nativePageTransitions: NativePageTransitions) {
    instance = this;
    this.innerInstance = this;
    this.tabAten = AtendimentosPage;
    this.tabEquip = EquipamentosPage;
    this.tabCad = MeuCadastroPage;
}

setTitle(title: String) {
    this.title = title;
}

setFilteredItems() {

    switch (this.tabs._getSelectedTabIndex()) {
        //THIS is where I'm trying to call the method inside the 1st tab. The setFilteredItems() method is called whenever the search bar receives new text from the user.
        case 0: this.tabAten.filterItems(this.searchTerm);
            break;
        case 1: this.tabEquip.filterItems(this.searchTerm);
            break;
        default: break;
    }
}
```

And here is the tab class:

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let a of atendimentos; let i = index" (click)="showDetails(i)">
            <div *ngIf="a.status != 'Concluído'">
               <!-- This is where data for each list item is displayed -->
            </div>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import { AtendimentoPage } from "../atendimentos/atendimento/atendimento";

import { Atendimento } from "../../../models/atendimento";

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'atendimentos.html'
})

export class AtendimentosPage {

    options: NativeTransitionOptions;
    atendimentos: Array<Atendimento>;
    homeInstance: any;

    ionViewWillEnter() {
        this.homeInstance.setTitle("Atendimentos");
    }

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController
        , private navParams: NavParams
        , private http: Http
        , private nativePageTransitions: NativePageTransitions) {
        this.homeInstance = navParams.data;
        this.atendimentos = new Array<Atendimento>();

        this.getAtendimentos(); // Method that does a web call to get array of objects, those will be filtered by the search bar.
    }

    public filterItems(searchTerm) {
        //THIS is the method that I want to call from the home page.
    }
}
```

When I create the tabs in my home page, I assign them a class at the home page constructor. The template already knows those are tab roots. How can I access the actual class instance of the selected tab/page, and use its methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the solution. It actually isn't something from angular itself, so this might just be a workaround, but a fully functional one.

At the homepage html, when I declare my tabs, I pass as rootParams a variable called "innerInstance", which holds an instance of the homepage object. Since I have that instance available for each tab, I can update homepage's references to the tabs from a class reference to an *actual* object, like so:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController
        , private navParams: NavParams
        , private http: Http
        , private nativePageTransitions: NativePageTransitions) {


        //Here I call the homepage instance and assign a new value to this tab's reference
        this.homeInstance = navParams.data;


        this.atendimentos = new Array<Atendimento>();

        ...
    }
```

This might have been a bit confusing at first, but now it's clear for me. If anyone stumbles at a similar issue, please let me know.